# Wordpress Landing Page Redirection Issue

Tags: url-rewriting

This might be a basic issue but I did not know the keywords to search it with.

I am working on a Wordpress site. The landing page has the following url:

`http://www.abc.com/home/`

But when I visit this url, the page is redirected to:

`http://www.abc.com/`

Although the template that loads on the url `http://www.abc.com/`, is the same which has to be loaded on the url `http://www.abc.com/home/`, but for some reasons I really want the `"/home/"` part.

The url works fine for other pages. That is if I visit "Contact" page, correct url is loaded in the address bar "`http://www.abc.com/contact/`"

This is the .htaccess file that I currently have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you tried [creating a static home page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)? Also, you could try to change the blog home at Config > General.

Comment: @mathielo I already have a static home page. I currently have version 3.6.1. I never had this issue before (I guess). Maybe it is related to the version.